# Is it possible to do a blend of ancient epic poems and modern novels?

Tags: creative-writing, dialogue, formatting

Is it possible to do a blend of ancient epic poems and modern novels? I was thinking of considering writing a short novel, which is a mix of ancient epic poems such as Iliad and a modern novel like Games of Thrones, but I don't think this is possible and if you mix them it would produce something that's not very good. The main problem would be how the dialogues would be introduced. You wouldn't be able to have long dialogues, which would make storytelling very difficult and the poetic parts wouldn't blend in well. Is there any case study of people who tried to do the same and were successful in doing so?

Comment: You might as well try. If it doesn't work, you've still learned something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it would certainly be **possible** to write such a mix. Whether it would work well or appeal to many readers would depend on the skill of the author and the exact way that these components were mixed.

One might, for instance, have a section of epic, followed by a chapter or two of prose, which would leave plenty of time for dialog in the prose.  Some ancient poems included considerable dialog, also. *Beowulf* comes to mind.

It might also depend on whether the prose retold the story from the verse, or gave a section of the plot not included in the verse provided.

Some  examples:

David Drake, in his *Northworld* Trilogy essentially retold several of the stories from the Norse *Elder Edda* in the form of an SF novel, but did not include extended verse directly. The same author, in his *Cross the Stars* retold the *Odyssey* as an SF novel, but again did not include any of the original verse.

J.R.R. Tolkien famously included a good deal of verse in *The Lord of the Rings*, and some of it was adaptions of actual ancient verse, but the overwhelming majority of that work is prose.